# Is there an equivalent in Net::SSH::Expect 1.09 for "collect_exit_code"

Tags: perl, perl-module, cgi-bin, perlnetssh

I came across this link: [Exit status code for Expect script called from Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302113/exit-status-code-for-expect-script-called-from-bash) but it did not help me.  As I was looking to get the exit status code from a command run remotely, I came across cpan documentation for Net::SSH::Expect 0.08 which has "collect_exit_code" and "last_exit_code" methods, which is exactly what I'd like to use *today*, however, I'm unable to find a suitable replacement when running 1.09.

I'd like to keep it simple, such as:

```
$ssh_devel_exp->collect_exit_code(1);
$ssh_devel_exp->send("sudo make");
if ($ssh_devel_exp->last_exit_code()) { etc. and so forth... };
```

But, I cannot think of a simple way to get the exit status when running a command through Net Expect without methods similar to these.

I do not believe switching to Fabric is the answer for this issue; this is a perl application and I need to stick with Perl.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use [Net::OpenSSH](https://metacpan.org/module/Net::OpenSSH)!

Comment: Well, that looks promising.  I'll have to give it a shot.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to call the underlying expect object?

```
$ssh_devel_exp->{expect}->collect_exit_code(1);
$ssh_devel_exp->send("sudo make");
if ($ssh_devel_exp->{expect}->last_exit_code()) { etc. and so forth... };
```

if nothing else helps you could create a small shell script that execute your commands and report back the exitstatus on stderr.

Comment: Hmm, perhaps I should have included the creation of the object...I create the object like so:

`my $ssh_devel_exp=Net::SSH::Expect->new(host=>$devel_server,user=>$USER,password=>$PASS_M,raw_pty=>1);`

That makes the 'call' ("->{expect}") superfluous, correct?

When I try your additions, I get:


ERROR: cannot find method `collect_exit_code' in class Expect at /usr/lib/cgi-bin/menu.pl line 217.